# Opening a specific page on first run

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In the `WMAppManifest.xml` I've set page A as the default page.

While that is fine 99.9% of the time, I need the user to see page B, at app's first run.

I'm not sure where to start with this, except maybe checking (in page A) whether "firstRun" key exists in the app's `IsolatedStorageSettings` properties, and navigate the user to page B.

That sounds like a hack to me, though. Is there a good-practice solution?

EDIT: I've tried googling, but I'm not sure which keywords to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom [`UriMapper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.urimapping%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is exactly what you need. Here [is the example](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2012/06/18/Using-a-custom-UriMapper-to-navigate-to-a-login-screen.aspx).

```
public class YourUriMapper : UriMapperBase
{
    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri.OriginalString == "/PageA.xaml")
        {
            if (AppSettings.FirstRun == true)
            {
                uri = new Uri("/PageB.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            }
            else
            {
                uri = new Uri("/PageA.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            }
        }
        return uri;
    }
}
```

where `AppSettings` is a user defined class to store application settings.

Comment: I assume `AppSettings` is a user-defined public static class?

Comment: Yep, I don't know how do you store your settings.

Comment: @Howie : If the provided solution solve your issue mark it as answered. Else update your current issue you are facing.

Comment: @NithaPaul It seems the SO community has multiple disorder syndrome, since I've been told I shouldn't mark the first answer as the solution too soon (within ~1 day, IIRC)... However, you'll notice that ALL my questions have marked a solution, so I'm unsure why you've even commented?

Comment: Hey nothing serious, I just asked ieall, I thought if you didn't get any answer means, someone else can help. :)\